# Using the 80:20 rule, what top 20% of economic concepts, theories, methods, tests, tools etc do you use to generate 80% of your results?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, statistics

I'm curious to see what different economists use in their roles. Helpful if you could specify your area of work/interest too.

Comment: 80% of  my conclusions boil down to confirmation bias. For the other 20 I appeal to authority.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a survey question.